# How do I filter EXTJS Grid list filters?

Tags: javascript, list, extjs, filter, grid

I have a **grid with list filters**. When I filter one column, the other list filters **are not filtered** with the results.

I did a [test fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/343r&view/editor) to exemplify this:
[image]
When I filter to **project leader role**, I only have one result with **active status** (Diana). But when I look at the status filters **I see both** (active and suspended):
[image] 
Is there any way that only the filters associated with the results are displayed?

Note: I'm using ExtJS 6.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by overriding the method `getOptionsFromStore` for list filter without concrete (with autogenerated from grid store) store. Or you can create new component based on it

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/344s&view/editor)

```js
Ext.define('Ext.grid.filters.filter.DynamicList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.filters.filter.List',
    alias: 'grid.filter.d-list',
    type: 'd-list',
    getOptionsFromStore: function (store) {

        var me = this,
            data = store.getData(),
            map = {},
            ret = [],
            dataIndex = me.dataIndex,
            labelIndex = me.labelIndex,
            recData, idValue, labelValue;

        if (store.isFiltered() && !store.remoteFilter ) {
            data = data.getSource();
        }

        //each filtered records, not all
        Ext.Array.each(store.getRange(),function (record) {
            recData = record.data;

            idValue = recData[dataIndex];
            labelValue = recData[labelIndex];

            if (labelValue === undefined) {
                labelValue = idValue;
            }

            if (!map[idValue]) {
                map[idValue] = 1;
                ret.push([idValue, labelValue]);
            }
        }, null, {
            filtered: true,
            collapsed: true
        });

        return ret;
    }
});
```